# requesting user permissions not working facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

hi i am using facebook graph api PHP SDK . here i am trying to get the logged in user's facebook details , currently i am getting only the basic details which are not required any permissions .

```
Array
(
    [id] => xxxxxxxxx
    [name] => Kanishka Bandara Panamaldeniya
    [first_name] => Kanishka
    [middle_name] => Bandara
    [last_name] => Panamaldeniya
    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/kanishka.panamaldeniya
    [username] => kanishka.panamaldeniya
    [hometown] => Array
        (
            [id] => 108014839219027
            [name] => Kandy
        )

    [location] => Array
        (
            [id] => 108602292505393
            [name] => Colombo, Sri Lanka
        )

    [quotes] => every action has a reaction....
    [work] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [employer] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 234117399957729
                            [name] => Cyber LMJ
                        )

                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 108602292505393
                            [name] => Colombo, Sri Lanka
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 109542932398298
                            [name] => Software Engineer
                        )

                    [start_date] => 2011-08
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [employer] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 235852306375
                            [name] => eMarketingEye
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 109542932398298
                            [name] => Software Engineer
                        )

                    [start_date] => 2010-09
                    [end_date] => 2011-08
                )

        )

    [sports] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 103992339636529
                    [name] => Cricket
                )

        )

    [favorite_teams] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 191485640872790
                    [name] => Sri Lanka Cricket Team
                )

        )

    [favorite_athletes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 185101794860886
                    [name] => Kumara Sangakkara
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 119473804782315
                    [name] => Angelo Mathews
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 164574093575397
                    [name] => Kumar Sangakkara
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 169411436417102
                    [name] => Virat Kohli
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 166273026737204
                    [name] => Lahiru Thirimanne
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 101237886616765
                    [name] => Dinesh Chandimal
                )

        )

    [education] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [school] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 34663330581
                            [name] => Dharmaraja College-Kandy
                        )

                    [year] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 138383069535219
                            [name] => 2005
                        )

                    [type] => High School
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [school] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 112872282058324
                            [name] => University of Colombo School of Computing
                        )

                    [year] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 140617569303679
                            [name] => 2007
                        )

                    [type] => College
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [school] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 107577089271805
                            [name] => University of Colombo
                        )

                    [type] => Graduate School
                    [with] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 705760115
                                    [name] => Lasitha Benaragama
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [gender] => male
    [timezone] => 5.5
    [locale] => en_US
    [languages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 104023029632921
                    [name] => Sinhala
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 106059522759137
                    [name] => English
                )

        )

    [verified] => 1
    [updated_time] => 2012-07-29T16:34:22+0000
)
```

now i want to get fields

```
*email 
*birth day
```

and some other permission requesting fields .

so i am doing

```
    $this->co_config_items = $this->ci->config->item('connections_config');
    $fbconfig = array(
    'appId' => $this->co_config_items['fb_appid'],
    'secret' => $this->co_config_items['fb_secret'],
    'cookie' => true,
    'domain' => $this->ci->config->item('domain')
    );

    $this->ci->load->library('3rd/connectors/facebook', $fbconfig);

    $facebook = new Facebook($fbconfig);
    Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
    Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;

    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                   'canvas' => 1,
                   'fbconnect' => 0,
                   'scope' => 'read_stream,friends_likes,user_birthday'
    ));     

    if(!$session){
        $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                   'canvas' => 1,
                   'fbconnect' => 0,
                   'scope' => 'read_stream,friends_likes,user_birthday'

                  ));

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = '$url';</script>";
    }
    else{
        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.location.href='" . base_url() . "home/auth/get_user_facebook_details_list" . "'; self.close();
        //</script>";
        try {

            $me = $facebook->api('/me');

            $this->ci->session->set_flashdata ( 'user_details',$me);
            $url=base_url()."home/auth/user_contact_information";               
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.opener.location.href = '$url';self.close();</script>";

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $this->ci->message->set_error(array('An errror occured , please try again'));
        }
    }
```

i am trying to ask permissions by

```
        $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                       'canvas' => 1,
                       'fbconnect' => 0,
                       'scope' => 'read_stream,friends_likes,user_birthday'
)):
```

**but it is not asking for any permission , the default array is always printing** . why is that . please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using the version 2 of PHP sdk , now i am using version 3 , now it is working , thank you very much . i saw some changes in two versions in this function

version 2

```
  public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
        $currentUrl = $this->getCurrentUrl();
        return $this->getUrl(
                'www',
                'login.php',
                array_merge(array(
                    'api_key' => $this->getAppId(),
                    'cancel_url' => $currentUrl,
                    'display' => 'page',
                    'fbconnect' => 1,
                    'next' => $currentUrl,
                    'return_session' => 1,
                    'session_version' => 3,
                    'v' => '1.0',
                        ), $params)
        );
    }
```

version 3

```
 public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
    $this->establishCSRFTokenState();
    $currentUrl = $this->getCurrentUrl();

    // if 'scope' is passed as an array, convert to comma separated list
    $scopeParams = isset($params['scope']) ? $params['scope'] : null;
    if ($scopeParams && is_array($scopeParams)) {
      $params['scope'] = implode(',', $scopeParams);
    }

    return $this->getUrl(
      'www',
      'dialog/oauth',
      array_merge(array(
                    'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                    'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                    'state' => $this->state),
                  $params));
  }
```

in version 3 this i can see this additional code

```
// if 'scope' is passed as an array, convert to comma separated list
    $scopeParams = isset($params['scope']) ? $params['scope'] : null;
    if ($scopeParams && is_array($scopeParams)) {
      $params['scope'] = implode(',', $scopeParams);
    }
```

in version 2 , there is nothing called scope .and also

in version 2

```
return $this->getUrl(
                    'www',
                    'login.php',
```

in version 3

```
return $this->getUrl(
          'www',
          'dialog/oauth',
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'read_stream,friends_likes,user_birthday'));
```